# Recreation of grid with flex box text alignment

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I am pretty new to flexbox and I am trying to get proficient with it. I am trying to recreate this grid with flexbox - it's pretty close but I am having trouble with the text alignment, How can I align the flexbox text the way the grid text is aligned?'

Edit: I don't know what's unclear about this. I am trying to make the flex box aligned left-center the same way the bottom grid is. The flex box is centered but not left justified.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.17/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

This is Flex:

        <div class="flex flex-wrap w-full justify-center items-center content-center text-center min-h-screen">


                <div class="flex flex-col w-full md:w-1/3 max-w-md bg-red-100">
                    <div class="py-12">
                    <h4 class="font-semibold tracking-widest text-xs">Box 1.1</h4>
                    <p>Box 1.1 Flexbox</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="flex flex-col w-full md:w-1/3 max-w-md bg-blue-100">
                    <div class="py-12">
                    <h4 class="font-semibold tracking-widest text-xs">Box 1.2</h4>
                    <p>Box 1.2 Flexbox</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="flex flex-col w-full md:w-1/3 max-w-md bg-green-100">
                    <div class="py-12">
                    <h4 class="font-semibold tracking-widest text-xs">Box 1.3</h4>
                    <p>Box 1.3 Flexbox</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        
        
        </div>
    
    This is Grid:
    
    <div class="flex flex-wrap w-full justify-center items-center content-center min-h-screen">



            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 mx-auto gap-24 lg:gap-48 xl:gap-56">
                <div class="bg-red-100">
                    <h4 class="font-semibold tracking-widest text-xs">Box 2.1</h4>
                    <p>Box 2.1 Flexbox</p>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-blue-100">
                    <h4 class="font-semibold tracking-widest text-xs">Box 2.2</h4>
                    <p>Box 2.2 Flexbox</p>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-green-100">
                    <h4 class="font-semibold tracking-widest text-xs">Box 2.3</h4>
                    <p>Box 2.3 Flexbox</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            
        </div>
```

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Please be more specific.

Comment: do you want to use tailwind framework? in pure css with `text-align : center` for every `div` you can do it.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin how is my question with an example not clear? I want to top to look like the bottom? Bottom is centered but left justified, top is just centered.

Comment: If the top had the same number of characters as the bottom, they would both align. That's why your question isn't clear.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin I don't think you scrolled down enough... I have edited my code example. please note how Box 1.1 does not have the same justification as Box 2.1

Comment: You're right. I hadn't scrolled down far enough. Apologies.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin - thanks, can you upvote my question so it gets some more attention?

Comment: I had already upvoted your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.17/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>




        <section class="flex flex-wrap w-full justify-center items-center content-center mt-20 lg:mt-0 min-h-85 fade fadeout">

            <div class="flex flex-col w-full md:w-1/3 max-w-md items-center bg-red-100">
                <div class="py-12 w-52 bg-red-200">
                    <h4 class="font-semibold tracking-widest text-xs">Box 1</h4>
                    <p>Box 1 Flexbox</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flex flex-col w-full md:w-1/3 max-w-md items-center bg-blue-100">
                <div class="py-12 w-52 bg-blue-200">
                    <h4 class="font-semibold tracking-widest text-xs">Box 2</h4>
                    <p>Box 2 Flexbox</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flex flex-col w-full md:w-1/3 max-w-md items-center bg-green-100">
                <div class="py-12 w-52 bg-green-200">
                    <h4 class="font-semibold tracking-widest text-xs">Box 3</h4>
                        <p>Box 4 Flexbox</p>
                </div>
            </div>


        </section>
```

If anyone has a better way let me know.

Comment: What's your solution? You used `flex-direction: column`?

Answer (score -1):

> How can I align the flexbox text the way the grid text is aligned?'

Can't be done (with plain CSS).

Grid establishes column tracks. You can align content within those tracks (hence, the left-alignment).

Flex has no such column tracks, just flex lines. This means that the content has nothing to left-align against (beyond the container borders). It can only align along the flex line based on the free space.